# Can we add a dynamic label to a Grafana alert?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts, grafana-templating

I am using Grafana 9.4 for dashboarding and alerting. I currently have an alert set up with:

- Query A:

  - a Prometheus metric with labels like `{tenant="tenant1", ...}` and legend set to `{{tenant}}`.
- Expression B (the alert condition):

  - Classic_conditions `WHEN last() of A is above 100`

When triggering, the alert currently generates a notification similar to:

```
Firing
Value: B0=222.28333333333333
Labels:
- alertname = My alert name
- grafana_folder = My folder
- team = my-team
Annotations:
- summary = My summary
...
```

1. Would it be possible to have a dynamic label that would contain my tenant's name? That way, I could silence the alert for a given tenant only? I tried a few values for the label thinking that some sort of templating was used but I couldn't get the proper syntax to have a value.
2. How can I at least replace the `B0` in the notification with the actual tenant name from query A?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use Grafana unified alerting (not old Grafana legacy alerting).

1. A: use query, which will group by `tenant` label
2. B: use expression with `Operation: Reduce`, `Function: Last`
3. C: use expression with `Operation: Math`, `Expression: $B>100`

Set alert condition: C - expression.

Use `Preview alerts` to verify that all labels are generated correctly.

Tenant label will be available in the alert `labels` section. Of course you can use it as `{{ $labels.B.tenant}}` in the alert `Description` or `Summary` field.

Comment: How can I tell whether I am using unified or legacy alerting? 

Your solution fixed the point 1 of my question in the sense that I now have a label `tenant=something`. The `{{ $labels.B.tenant}}` in the summary yielded `[no value]` but since I got a new label named `tenant` I tried `{{ $labels.tenant }}` and it worked!

Comment: @MarcelGosselin use `Preview alerts` and verify where are labels generated.